# Errors were encountered while processing: grub-efi-amd64-signed - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: grub-efi

I have updated my ubuntu server from 16.xx to 18.xx to now Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get purge grub\*
sudo apt-get install grub-efi
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
```

But still got the error.

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but still got the error.

```
root@xxx:~# sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@xxx:~#
```

I have no idea what to do next since all the google searches are giving me few solutions which aren't working.

Comment: root@xxx:~# dpkg --get-selections | grep grub
grub-common                                     install
grub-efi                                        deinstall
grub-efi-amd64                                  deinstall
grub-efi-amd64-bin                              install
grub-efi-amd64-signed                           install
grub-gfxpayload-lists                           install
grub-pc                                         install
grub-pc-bin                                     install
grub2-common                                    install
root@xxx:~#

Answer (score 0):

Update from today has resolved the issue:

```
grub-common/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.4]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.4]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/focal-updates 1.142.8+2.04-1ubuntu26.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4]
grub-efi-amd64/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.4]
grub-efi/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.4]
grub2-common/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.4]
```