# Error Reading EFI Variable (SecureBoot) During Upgrade, grub-efi-amd64-signed and shim-signed Update Failed

Tags: boot, server, grub2, 20.04, uefi

A few weeks ago, I performed a regular software update on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS using the commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Normally, this process finishes without any problems, but this time it froze while setting up `secureboot-db`. After pressing Crtl+C to stop the update for that package, `apt` continued with the upgrade and got into some other problems: `grub-install` couldn't install for x86_64-efi platform.

After a bit of research, I found that others had the same issue and 'solved' it by cancelling the update of the `secureboot-db` package (https://askubuntu.com/a/1095718). All went fine for the next update: the grub was updated and I could reboot back into Ubuntu without any issues.

Today, I needed to install a new package and thought it was a good idea to `apt upgrade` before doing that. A few minutes later, I was greeted with a red popup saying:

```
### Configuring grub-efi-amd64 ###
GRUB failed to install to the following devices: /dev/sda1
Do you want to continue anyway? If you do, your computer may not start up properly.
YES - NO
```

After selecting NO, it asked me to select the efi partition (which was already selected) and try to install it again. After a few seconds, the red popup returned. Eventually, I pressed YES and the upgrade continued, exiting with 2 failed packages: `grub-efi-amd64-signed` and `shim-signed`.

Here is the full output for `apt upgrade`:

```
~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142.8+2.04-1ubuntu26.6) ...
od: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SecureBoot-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c: read error: Interrupted system call
/usr/share/grub/grub-check-signatures: 22: [: Illegal number: 
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So it appears there's an issue reading the EFI variable `SecureBoot`.

**Should I be worried? How can I upgrade these packages without any errors? Will I be able to boot normally?**

I haven't rebooted my machine yet, because I'm afraid it might not boot back into Ubuntu.

I've read some other posts and websites, but none address the same issues I have:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/53203528 is about an error while processing `grub-efi-amd64-signed` and `shim-signed`, but the error message say that there is "no space left on device". I'm getting an error reading an EFI variable.
- [Errors were encountered while processing: grub-efi-amd64-signed - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/1284218) also has errors upgrading `grub-efi-amd64-signed`, but got the issue resolved by waiting two weeks for a new update.
- [error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed ubuntu 20.4](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230135/1143914) appears to have a similar issue to mine, but doesn't specify any error messages. The error exit status is also different.
- [Errors during upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 (shim-signed and grub-efi-amd64-signed)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031066/1143914) also has a similar issue, but `grub-install` can't add an entry to `BootOrder`.
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/Testing gives an overview of how SecureBoot works. Somewhere down on that page, there's a note that says: "**IMPORTANT:** improperly updating secureboot-db could result in all systems with Secure Boot enabled failing to boot.". I wonder if it was a good idea to remove that package.

I believe SecureBoot is disabled on my machine, but I can't go back and check it, since I might not get back into Ubuntu.

Here are the outputs of some other commands:

```
~$ sudo grub-install
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: Cannot read EFI Boot* variables.
grub-install: warning: efivarfs_get_variable: read failed: Interrupted system call.
grub-install: warning: efi_get_variable: ops->get_variable failed: Interrupted system call.
grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Interrupted system call.

~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-51-generic
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
done

~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop1    7:1    0  69.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18077
loop2    7:2    0  69.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18013
loop3    7:3    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9721
loop5    7:5    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9607
loop6    7:6    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1932
sda      8:0    0 279.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   279G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do not know issue, but you can see if Secure boot is on. `sudo bootctl --path /boot/efi status
`

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue, and this seems to be a bug from Ubuntu (cf [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1872212) and [there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1874610) for example). Not sure what to do except for waiting for the bug to be fixed